# R: Divide rows by row totals using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr, janitor

I have seen a variety of posts that detail how to do a similar function, but I have yet to find one that divides all rows by a reference row while excluding the reference row itself.

Here is an example set of data with required packages:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

d <- tibble(
  level = as.factor(c(1:10)),
  var_1 = sample(c(1:20), 10),
  var_2 = sample(c(1:30), 10),
  var_3 = sample(c(1:40), 10),
  var_4 = sample(c(1:50), 10),
)
```

In the following code, I am dividing each row by the `Total` row generated by `adorn_totals()`:

```
d %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-level), funs(round(./.[11]*100, 2)))
```

Here is the output:

```
level  var_1  var_2 var_3  var_4
    1   3.66  13.89   6.0   6.50
    2  10.98  11.11   0.5   8.94
    3   4.88   7.64  14.0  15.45
    4   6.10  18.06  16.0   7.72
    5  18.29  13.19  10.0   9.35
    6  14.63  10.42  11.5   3.25
    7   2.44   6.25  12.5  19.51
    8   8.54  11.81  13.5   4.07
    9  23.17   3.47   1.0  20.33
   10   7.32   4.17  15.0   4.88
Total 100.00 100.00 100.0 100.00
```

But, I want to calculate these proportions of the total **without** impacting the `Total` row itself. Below I've attached the desired output with the row totals untouched while the rest of the rows have been mutated per my function.

```
level  var_1  var_2 var_3  var_4
    1   3.66  13.89   6.0   6.50
    2  10.98  11.11   0.5   8.94
    3   4.88   7.64  14.0  15.45
    4   6.10  18.06  16.0   7.72
    5  18.29  13.19  10.0   9.35
    6  14.63  10.42  11.5   3.25
    7   2.44   6.25  12.5  19.51
    8   8.54  11.81  13.5   4.07
    9  23.17   3.47   1.0  20.33
   10   7.32   4.17  15.0   4.88
Total  82    144    200   246
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `adorn_percentages` does the same thing as your custom function.

```
d %>% 
  adorn_percentages("col") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-level), ~round(.*100,2)) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    d %>% adorn_totals("row") %>% slice(11)
  )
```

Comment: This works perfect, though it could be made more generic by changing `slice(11)` to `slice(n())`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `replace` here.  Here, the `n()` gives the index of the last row and `-n()` removes the last row from the calculation.  In `replace`, the index vector argument (`list`) can take a logical or numeric index

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
d %>%
   adorn_totals("row") %>%
   mutate_at(vars(-level), list(~replace(., row_number() < n(),
                   round(.[-n()]/.[n()]*100, 2))))
```

Comment: This works great! Though, the custom function is a little difficult for me to follow.

Comment: @Craig  In thee `replace`, we are subsetting the elements by removing the last row and divide with the last row to replace the values other than the last row